# Querying a MongoDB database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, mongodb-.net-driver

I am building an C# EntitySetController, what is the most efficient way to use it to query a MongoDB database? Would using Odata queries against either an IQueryable collection or MongoCursor collection be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you go with IQueryable collection, it is also supported by MongoDB. E.g.:

```
public IQueryable<EntityType> Get()
{
    return database.GetCollection<EntityType>("EntitySetName").AsQueryable();
}
```

where `database` is an instance of `MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase` of the [MongoDB C# driver](http://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/).